# Git - File is on github but also on .gitignore - What happens on git pull?

Tags: git, github, repository, gitignore

What happens if you have a file on remote, that is locally on .gitignore, when you do a pull? Will you overwrite the content of the local file?

Comment: `.gitignore` ignores only **untracked files**. Files that are tracked (committed) are updated as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If the files is already in version control it will stay in version control, meaning other users will see it.  You will need to remove the file manually.  To delete the file but not remove it from your directory you can use

```
git rm --cached file
```

To do it to every file you can use

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

The file/files will not stay on the disk for long as git will know to remove it.   Switch to another branch and then back — the file will be removed.  This applies to anyone who pulls down the branch

Comment: So "git rm --cached file" will remove "file" from version control, right? Meaning the local version will stay after a Git pull

Comment: It will not stay on disk for long. Switch to another branch and then back — the file will be removed because `git` know it must not be there. If any of your collaborators pull the repository the file will be removed.